# Pygame window not popping in python using pycharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently trying to study python using the Python Crash Course book but I have halted right now because I can't go forward with the first project. Whenever I run my program in pycharm or IDLE, all I get is a message saying "pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.6)
Hello from the pygame community. [https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html"](https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html%22) with no window for the pygame popping up, my code is below, thank you for whoever can help me:
EDIT: My OS is Windows 10 21H1, Currently using pycharm 2021.1 with python 3.9.6 and pygame 2.0.1

```
import sys

import pygame


class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: The problem is not with your code, but with your system.

Comment: It’s possible that this issue is that you are using python 3.9. Because it’s the newest version, some packages, possibly including pygame, may break.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh my bad, I just new that newer versions of python could break some modules so I assumed it was that.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I see, is it possible that it might be a problem with the python installation then? thanks a lot!

Comment: @CmdCoder858 I tried running it with a 3.7 earlier but I'll try another more version in that case, thanks!

Comment: Possibly @CmdCoder858 i right. You use python 3.9.6. This might be a problem.

Comment: I see, I'll try and install other versions too in that case, and test them one by one, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm at loss here. I tried different versions of 3.5/6/7/8/ and 9 but no luck, same outcome. I'll try to scour the net for more possible diagnosis clues but so far no luck. I also tried uninstalling and installing the python versions themselves but again no luck

Comment: Pygame has worked on Python 3.9 for quite a while now. I just ran this code against a fresh install of Python 3.9.6 and Pygame 2.0.1, and I see an empty Pygame window on macOS. I can't run this on Windows at the moment. Do you get any different results if you run this program from a terminal rather than running it through PyCharm?

Comment: @japhyr yeah, I've run it from the terminal and from IDLE, both resulted in no luck. I might try running it in my Linux VM and see if the problem will persist.

Comment: Huh weird, for some reason because of the pygame not working I tried working on another project (which is about using the matplot library and when I tried running the program again today it works in all the terminals as well as IDEs. idk what went wrong in the first place but it's all working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed, I tried doing another project first (one the utilizes matplot library and it was magically fixed when I tried it again.)